# Should I reclass Lissa or upgrade her?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I was going to reclass her, but also I want her to be a sage. What should I do? I'm on Arc 2, and I just completed the level in which you unlock Henry. It's not that I don't know who to use a Master Seal on, it's just I haven't decided on what to do with Lissa yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use a Master Seal in Fire Emblem: Awakening?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116011/when-should-i-use-a-master-seal-in-fire-emblem-awakening)

Comment: In *Awakening* you can re-class units as many times as you want, so it doesn't really matter. Just make sure to get the skills you want from the classes available to her.

Comment: What goal are you going for?  This is currently both too subjective to properly answer, and too vague to be able to help.  We need you to provide more information.

Comment: I want to beat the game... I don't know what you mean otherwise.

Comment: We're not here to help you decide what to do with your character; that's not part of what Arqade does.  Do you have a goal in mind *for Lissa*?  What do you want her to do?  If you don't know that, there's not much we can do for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

It doesn't matter.

---

Long answer:

You can reclass or promote any character including those with a unique class as often as you want, as long as you have a [**Second Seal**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Seal) (reclassing) or a [**Master Seal**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Seal) (promotion). Those can be bought freely from merchants and are very affordable.

You can even use the Second Seal to demote a character if you wish. Any stats lost in the process due to lower stat caps are awarded back on promotion.

Since reclassing resets the character's level to 1 but not his/her stats, you will eventually reclass your characters a lot in order to make them learn useful skills and maximize their stats.

Simply experiment with reclassing until you've decided which class you want to keep Lissa in. By then, she'll be an extremely powerful asset in your army, assuming you're still using her.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when re-classing for skills is that, at first, combat is probably going to suck. Because you've likely just re-classed into something that uses an entirely different weapon, and you are back to grade E grade weapons. But some skills, like Galeforce (from the Dark Flier), are well worth the extra effort.

Comment: Galeforce is so incredibly cool, I try to get it with every character who can. Not that they have to stay Dark Fliers afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little subjective because there are so many reclassing options in Awakening, but Lissa is designed to be a good healer, so you would benefit to keep her in a class that can use staves. Sage is a good option as well as Falcon Knight.

If you just want to obtain more skills, you can reclass her to any number of other classes before finally upgrading to a Sage or Falcon Knight. Naturally this takes a lot more time and training investment.